# Javascript not working in go webserver

Tags: javascript, go, webserver

main.go

```
func thandle(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("basic.html")// 
    t.Execute(rw, nil)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", thandle)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9999", nil)
}
```

I don't understand. 
Which part wrong?

basic.html

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         alert('hey');
     });</script>
</head>
```

if you can
show me right code example?

Comment: Where do you think Javascript will come into play? Your program will serve `basic.html` and that's it...

Comment: It's clear you lack a basic understanding of how the web works; This however is being assumed by most go-related material (as it is a new language, there isn't much beginner material out there). You should probably look into something more established before taking another jab at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue not related to Go. Try:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         alert('hey');
     });</script>
</head>
```

You need to understand what is the different beetwen client-side and server-side programming. Maybe these link will help you:

1. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming
2. http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/

If you want to host your own js file (an other static file) so you can use realtive url (don't need to change your HTML code) see http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer_stripPrefix

Comment: it's due to your first version expecing to get jquery from your server.  nvcnvn's answer changed that to get it from jquery.com.  Your server isn't setup to vend more than just "basic.html".

Comment: Your answer was a big help. Thnak you!